# Test accuracy evaluation Callback

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0

I would like to compute the test accuracy after each epoch during the training of a neural network. Simple solution would be:

```
for i in range(NUM_EPOCHS): 
    model.fit(train_dataset,epochs=1)
    accuracy = model.evaluate(test_dataset)
    test_accuracy_list.append(accuracy)
```

Is there any more modular solution by using Callbacks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is `on_epoch_end`

```
class EvaluateEpochEnd(tf.keras.callbacks.Callback):
    def __init__(self, test_data):
        self.test_data = test_data

    def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs={}):
        x, y = self.test_data
        scores = self.model.evaluate(x, y, verbose=False)
        print('\nTesting loss: {}, accuracy: {}\n'.format(scores[0], scores[1]))
```

Usage:

```
model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=5, callbacks=[EvaluateEpochEnd((x_test, y_test))])
```

Will give:

```
Epoch 1/5
1875/1875 [==============================] - 6s 3ms/step - loss: 0.4784 - accuracy: 0.8619

Testing loss: 0.14208272099494934, accuracy: 0.9574000239372253
```

Comment: Thanks! I think this is the most elegant solution

Answer (score 0):

You can use a custom training loop like [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/writing_a_training_loop_from_scratch)

The method you have mentioned is incorrect, The method specified by you won't do the required thing. Instead it calls the fit functions multiple times.

The keras fit function returns you only the step loss/acc and not the epoch loss/acc

Comment: Can you expand your answer? I believe running fit with epochs=1 for 100 times is the same as running one single fit with epochs=100. Regarding your answer, I exactly need a custom training loop, but I don't know how to write a custom Callback that returns a test accuracy vector