# tf.keras Evaluate both train and validation in evaluate mode after each epoch

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tf.keras

I want to evaluate both train and validation in evaluate mode after each epoch, like setting `training=False` .

how to use tf.keras and

```py
model.fit(train, epochs=EPOCH,callbacks=callbacks,validation_data=[train, valid])
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [test-accuracy-evaluation-callback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67126690/test-accuracy-evaluation-callback/67128710#67128710)

Comment: thanks, `on_epoch_end` is what i need, although it needs another work to write tensorboard  : )